# Saving tkinter variables to txt file error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make my program save some tkinter String variables to a txt files.

Here is the code:

```
def saveFile():
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w')
    if file != None:
        file.write(seat1, seat2, seat3, seat4, seat5)
        file.close()
```

Then I get an error when I try to save the file:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Teacher Plan\seat-plan.py", line 64, in saveFile
    file.write(seat1, seat2, seat3, seat4, seat5)
TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (5 given)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you expecting all the seats to be combined as one string? You need to do that manually before passing the data to `write`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I just tried  `data = [seat1, seat2, seat3, seat4, seat5]` but got the error `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Teacher Plan\seat-plan.py", line 65, in saveFile
    file.write(data)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list   `

Comment: Read that error message again. What type does it say that it's expecting?

Comment: string but I don't get it, the variable is a string,  some advice would be nice

Comment: file.write have just 1 parameter.

Comment: You can't use multiple parameters in `file.write`, just join them (`file.write(seat1+seat2+seat3+seat4+seat5)`/`file.write(seat1+'\n'+seat2+'\n'+seat3+'\n'+seat4+'\n'+seat5)`). Hope that is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Make ALL your variables into 1 variable seat[0], seat[1], seat[2], seat[3], seat[4] and then save (seat)

I've used this in one of my projects and it works fine

First you define your main varibale at the start

```
ess=[[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

Then you make your work with variables, when you're done you save (or append) then into the single variable and save to file

```
    ess[0].append(ess_e), ess[1].append(essv), ess[2].append(essp), ess[3].append(essq), ess[4].append(ess_s), ess[5].append(ess_d)
    file = open("relais.txt", "w")
    file.write(repr(ess) + "\n")
    file.close()
```